# Is there a way to have simultaneous two linux running such that they can be swapped in seconds with a physical key

Tags: linux

I want to install two different linux distributions on the same PC.(I know that the best method to my knowledge is either dual boot or VMware). but the extra feature that i want is also to **swap the operating systems with a physical key** in just a second(or maybe 2).

**An Add-on optional question-**
Can a hacker retrieve data from other linux distro while I am running another linux

Comment: I don't understand your question, you said `I want to install two different linux distributions on the same PC.(I know that the best is dual boot or VMware)` - so how are you going to install actually install the second OS - using dualboot or VMware?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk i will edit it to - best to my knowledge

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I want to ask for suggestions maybe a feature that i am not aware of or any other feasible method to accomplish my task

Comment: vSphere Hypervisor?

Comment: what do you mean by `swap`? ... if two VMware instances are running on a PC then Alt-Tab would switch the focus between them

Comment: Please ask only one question at the time - move your `Add-on optional question` to the new question.

Comment: You can probably find a VM environment that allows switching in and out via Alt-Tab, or possibly some other hot key. If you want to get _more_ physical then that (considering the keyboard is necessarily handled by the OS in the end, so in software), you could get two separate machines and use a KVM switch. I do wonder what your use-case is, though, that may have a big effect on what solution to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run more than 1 operating system on the same machine
you have at least 3 options:

Run one system natively and run the other one at the same time inside
Docker container. Containers are small and lightweight, usually
slimmed down to take less space, they share kernel with the host OS
(the one installed natively), do not come with their own init and
usually do not come with X/Wayland so running GUI programs inside them
can be problematic. Docker containers are extremely popular among
software developers as you can use them to quickly re-create the
development environment and make sure that everyone uses the same
versions of compilers, shared libraries, Python packages, etc.

Run one system natively and run the other at the same time inside
virtual machine supervisor such as VMware or Virtualbox. I have never
used VMware but Virtualbox is free and works very well. However, make
sure that you have enough RAM to run 2 operating systems at the same
time, modern desktop Linux distributions require at least 2GB of RAM
to work as intended.

Run both systems natively - you cannot run 2 of them at the same time
though. And yes, it would possible to cycle between them using a
keyboard shortcut but it would require some manual setup:

1. Setup hibernation on both systems. You don't need to have a swap
   partition prepared in advance, swapfile would work as well.
2. Use efibootmgr to choose the next system that will booted after the
   reboot as explained at
   https://superuser.com/questions/1016762/is-it-possible-to-select-which-system-to-boot-before-rebooting-on-a-multi-boot.
3. Tell kernel to reboot instead of shutting down the next time
   hibernation is done by doing `echo reboot | sudo tee /sys/power/disk`.
4. When the required system is up restore the original behavior by
   doing `echo platform | sudo tee/sys/power/disk`

You can create a script that would do steps 2-4 for you and optionally
assign a keyboard shortcut to run the script.

Comment: you have mentioned atleast, so can i assume that there are more options.

Comment: thanks though..

Comment: I believe there might be more options to achieve that but I don't know any, Vagrant is the only thing that comes to my mind at the moment but it's a wrapper over virtual machine supervisor. But I can imagine a professional solutions used in datacenters that I have never heard of.

Comment: Depending on what you need `chroot` might be another alternative.  The hibernation solution is very elegant.